# Combining one or more characters (`+?`) and positive lookahead (?=)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"resourceType": "com.bmc.arsys.rx.services.view.domain.ContainerViewComponentDefinition",
```

I want to match the first double quote in this part:

```
"resourceType":
```

So I construct a regexp to find `"`, then one or more characters (greedy) followed by `":` literals, so I have the first part:

```
".+?
```

and then I want to add positive lookahead part `?=":`

```
".+??=":
```

but I get syntax error. What's the syntax for combining them?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  ".+?(?=")

Answer (score 3):

This simple one should suit your needs: `"[^"]+"`

Comment: that's a good solution, thanks, but I was more curios about the syntax of combining the two parts

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need. Use a lookahead group. The group is part of the syntax for lookahead.

```
".+?(?=")
```

Here's a good link that describes lookahead. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

UPDATE: remove extraneous suggestion, add comments to explanation.

Comment: thanks, so they can't be combined without using a group?

Comment: Yes. There are limitations in the regex syntax. Also, there are differences between regex implementations. Are you using GNU/Linux tools or M$FT tools? You'll find that sometimes, a regex search pattern will work differently or not at all as compared from one to the other.

Comment: @Maximus `(` and `)` are part of the lookahead syntax (which is `(?=pattern)`), so this is required. This is not a capturing group though.

Comment: @SebastianProske, ah, silly me, missed that part :(. You can post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

To match anything in between quotes you can do this. You don't need a positive look ahead.
`".+":`

Answer (score 2):

You could use both negative and positive lookahead.

```js
var str = '"resourceType": "com.bmc.arsys.rx.services.view.domain.ContainerViewComponentDefinition"'; 
    console.log(str.match(/(?!")\w+(?=")/)[0]);
```

Comment: `(?!")\w+` is rather pointless, as `"` is never a word character.